# Flutter Run Error: Supplied javaHome must be a valid directory. You supplied: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1 in flutter project

Tags: java, flutter

I tried to downgrade my Java SDK as there was an error with the latest version with flutter. In doing so, I have created this issue, which I cannot fix. The issue comes up when I run Flutter run.
The image is my Environment variables.
[image]

If i create a new flutter project it works fine, this error only comes up in my existing project